# Чем плохо хранить картинки в MySQL blob?

Tags: изображения, mysql

Здравствуйте! Скажите, пожалуйста, какие есть минусы и подводные камни в хранении картинок в `MySQL blob`, если они будут храниться в отдельном сервисе, соответственно, не создавая проблем с `io`?

Comment: вопрос, а зачем вообще файлы, хранить в базе? тем более файлы изображений, чем файловая система не база данных для файлов?

Comment: @ToRcH565 случаи разные бывают, например - сервер БД куда шустрее чем сервер приложений, удобство, виртуальные файлухи (например с автоматической обработкой метатегов)

Comment: "например - сервер БД куда шустрее чем сервер приложений"
Очень спорное утверждение, если под сервером понимается машинка или виртуалка - так повесьте на нее обязаности файло сервера помимо базы, если вы о том что БД шустрее нежели файловая система - момент крайне спорен.
Тело файла хранить в бд в любом случае менее выгодно нежели в файле.
Храните в базе файловые атрибуты, а само тело на винчестере. тут вам и быстрый поиск по тегам и быстрое получение файла.

Comment: @ToRcH565 железо быстрее у сервера БД... я это имел ввиду.

Comment: Выдачу будет все равно делать сервер приложений, при этом например картинку которая весит 10 МБ нужно передать с сервера БД на сервер приложений, где она будет загружена в оперативную память методом аналогичным mysql_fetch_row, после этого на сервере приложений эти данные нужно разместить в поток вывода, что производит тройную работу в отличие от файлов, которые позволяют отдавать данные не копируя их полностью в оперативную память, а отдавая порции по мере чтения (функция readfile), если удастся повторить это с БД, тогда можно предположить, что БД способна справиться с задачей за то же время

Comment: блобы тоже можно передавать не копируя полностью и при грамотной сети их не обязательно гонять через главную аппликуху

Comment: Разве можно заголовки отдать например PHP, а тело уже как-то выдавать средствами БД в рамках одного подключения?  
Или напрямую подключать пользователя к БД нужно? Тогда да, РНР не нужен вообще.

Answer (score 8):

- файловая система значительно быстрее отдаст файл, чем БД. Файловая система создана для работы с файлами, что не сказать о БД.
- файлы всегда надо отдавать динамически, так как средствами сценария надо выставить заголовки ответа соответствующие изображению.
- в БД придется хранить файловые атрибуты вроде даты последнего изменения итп, дабы обеспечить кэширование файлов браузерами.
- большой объем базы данных.
- список далеко не полный

Comment: @RainRaus первый пункт весьма спорный, второй несущественный, 3й не может считаться проблемой, как и 4й, 

@sokol99 если решитесь, погуглите barraccuda mysql, это для блобов важно.

ну и да - надо более детально прорабатывать такие схемы, например чтобы траффик между сервером базы и сервером приложений не гонять. А вообще щас модно cdn делать вместо своего хранилища media.

Comment: @RainRaus а как же, клиент-серверные приложения? Всё это дело туда сюда гонять через порты?